# Loading Views ObjC Single View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, methods, view

The way I went about coding my app was to load my views through methods in my ViewController.m file.'s implementation. After loading views my app progressed through menus and displays by button actions and updated my setting the self.view to different displays generated by my methods. The problem with this is my memory consumption. Each time a button is pressed my methods that display the next "view" becomes a child and so on. This chews up memory like crazy and I don't want to recode everything (I didn't use storyboard I used only coded). I tried creating a method in an infinite loop that switched views but it wouldn't update self.view. I need a way of switching views using only code (displaying my views with storyboard isn't possible, too complicated to align).

example code:

```html
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
...global vars...
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...setup...
    [self Load_Main_Menu];
}
-(void)Load_Main_Menu {

    ...setup UIView display...
    UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayButtonPressed:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.view=display;
}
-(void)PlayBt:(UIButton*)sender{
    [self load_Other_Menus];
}
```

All navigation and UI is handled as such.
Any ideas for improving memory management and navigation?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...setup...
    [self setupButton];
    [self displayView];
}

-(void)setupButton {
    UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayView)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ..add button to view
}

-(void)displayView {

    ...setup UIView display...

    self.view=display;
}
```

Comment: The problem still remains that as i click buttons each new method called becomes a child and chews up memory. Imagine that every time i click a menu button and then click the back button and repeat the methods stack up and gradually ram memory exceeds 150mb. Each method is 10-30mb but because the previous now parent method isn't released the memory just adds up. Buttons and everything work fine i just want to know how to prevent this stack of parent functions.

Comment: Forgot to mention that setting all buttons in view.didload will be difficult because i generate menus dependent of which menus are clicked. I try to play with this idea a bit by seeing up a button in view.didload, but every time i create a button i just edit the characteristics of this one button so it acts like a template allowing me create multiple buttons while having only one function act as it's parent. I still would appreciate any other ideas!

Comment: too little infomation.If you do like what i said i can't see any memory release problem.Sorry for my poor english,may you can provide all code in .m and we can see what's wrong with you.